Using next js node and tailwind... vs code says tailwind is not being recognized
was following this tutorial text , inside the globas.css.  at 9:00 min in vid after i type @apply text-sm; it says , uknown at rule @apply css , i asked chat gpt and it says tailwind is not being recongised but couldnt fix it, pls help
commands used in the terminal:
i did these commands: npx create-next-app@latest
then: npm i @mui/x-data-grid @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled lucide-react numeral recharts uuid axios
then:  npm i -D @types/node @types/uuid @types/numeral
when i open globals.css and hover on @tailwind base it says: Unknown at rule @tailwindcss
enter image description here
help making vs code recognize tailwind

Try using their VSCode extension pack: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
Probably doesn't hurt to follow their recommended settings section too:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#recommended-vs-code-settings
